# jenkins.plugins.publish_over.BapPublisherException: Failed to connect and initialize SSH connection. target instance OS amazon linux 2023

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2, ssh, amazon-linux, amazon-linux-2

When I am trying to SSH from jenkins to EC2 instance its giving the below error:

```
jenkins.plugins.publish_over.BapPublisherException: Failed to connect and initialize SSH connection. Message: [Failed to connect session for config [Frontend-Exa]. Message [Auth fail]]
```

Similarly i just launced another instance with the same configuration and it worked. Only difference is only the instance OS type

Amazon linux 2 - Working fine

Amazon linux 2023 - getting above error.

Can anyone guide me with workaround to fix the issue